# ROS Melodic Packages Missing (Buildfarm Issue?)

Tags: ros, ros-melodic, buildfarm

[image: Rosanswers logo]

So I am trying to install the following packages on a few systems with Melodic:

- ros-melodoc-rosdoc-lite ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/rosdoc_lite), [bionic_jenkins_job](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_uB64/job/Mbin_uB64__rosdoc_lite__ubuntu_bionic_amd64__binary), [stretch_jenkins_job](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_ds_dS64/job/Mbin_ds_dS64__rosdoc_lite__debian_stretch_amd64__binary))
- ros-melodoc-navigation ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation), [bionic_jenkins_job](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_uB64/job/Mbin_uB64__navigation__ubuntu_bionic_amd64__binary), [stretch_jenkins_job](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_ds_dS64/job/Mbin_ds_dS64__navigation__debian_stretch_amd64__binary))
- ros-melodoc-map-server ([wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/map_server?distro=melodic), [bionic_jenkins_job](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_uB64/job/Mbin_uB64__map_server__ubuntu_bionic_amd64__binary), [stretch_jenkins_job)](http://build.ros.org/view/Mbin_ds_dS64/job/Mbin_ds_dS64__map_server__debian_stretch_amd64__binary)

In each case the wiki.ros.org shows that they have packages for melodic, and that the jenkins binary jobs passed for both stretch and bionic, but they are not available in packages.ros.org.

They also are not in the packages file for the their respective disto ([bionic](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/bionic/main/binary-amd64/Packages), [stretch](http://packages.ros.org/ros/ubuntu/dists/stretch/main/binary-amd64/Packages))

So my main question are this packages released for Melodic and is the wiki correct with its status of the respective packages?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/300598/ros-melodic-packages-missing-(buildfarm-issue?)/) by [qnetjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27506/qnetjoe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2018-08-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The status page can give you more detailed information:

- http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=rosdoc
- http://repositories.ros.org/status_page/ros_melodic_default.html?q=map_server

The three squares in each column (which represent the different platforms) indicated the availability of that package (also see the legend on the page).

All packages have two green square and the third square is red. That means the latest version is available in the `building` repo (first square) as well as the `testing` repo (second square). The package isn't available in the `main` repo yet (third square). After packages have been successfully built they are being manually synced into the main repo after some soak period. Those syncs are being announced on discourse and enumerate what packages have been added / updated / removed since the last sync.

You can either wait a couple of weeks or (if you are brave / experienced) try the packages from the testing repo (sometimes also called "shadow-fixed").

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2018-08-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [qnetjoe](https://answers.ros.org/users/27506/qnetjoe/) on 2018-08-14**:
Thank you Dirk, that explains a lot.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2018-08-15**:\

> You can either wait a couple of weeks or (if you are brave / experienced) try the packages from the testing repo (sometimes also called "shadow-fixed").

Some info on how to set that up: [wiki/ShadowRepository](http://wiki.ros.org/ShadowRepository).